# I can't find my .vdi on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, vdi

I can't find my .vdi on Ubuntu.  I see it in my Virtual Box under storage as

```
Controller:SATA  
    SATA Port 0:     
    UbuntuLinux.vdi (Normal 10.00 GB)
```

However when I search in Ubuntu for the file I can't find it anywhere.

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser, so that your question could be more effectively addressed, can you elaborate on the Linux Version and clarify whether it is a LIVE booter or installed version ?

Comment: @UncertainWhatNameToPickHere No LSB modules are available.
> Distributor ID: Ubuntu
> Description: Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS
> Release: 16.04
> Codename: xenial

Comment: @UncertainWhatNameToPickHere It is also installed through virtualbox on my PC.